# Does log4net log on the current thread?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

Quick question - investigating some throughput issues and one item I'd like to tick off is to whether log4net logs on the current thread or not?

We have a number of appenders including a dbAppender - if the logging is done inline on the current thread then a significant amount of log messaging would result in a lot of db writes on the current thread..

Comment: Never thought about that but I do not see why it shouldn't? It is generally thread-safe and yes, logging affects performance.... I remember faintly that you can configure some buffering though ...

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on the used appender. log4net will just call the append method from every connected appender, so this happens within the same thread. The base class to implement an appender [`AppenderSkeleton`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/develop/src/Appender/AppenderSkeleton.cs) uses (the maybe not ideal and recommended way) `lock(this)` within these methods to avoid multi-threading problems.

The default appender to write into a SQL database is the [`AdoNetAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/develop/src/Appender/AdoNetAppender.cs). This one is not directly derived from the skeleton. Instead there is another base class *in between* of them. That is the [`BufferingAppenderSkeleton`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/develop/src/Appender/BufferingAppenderSkeleton.cs). This has an additional property `BufferSize` which will be used to only forward all cached log messages in an array if the buffer size is reached to the derived class method.

This is used by [`AdoNetAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/develop/src/Appender/AdoNetAppender.cs) to call the SQL server only when the buffer size is reached and is a good feature especially for client/server communications like in our SQL case.

So for your part: If you use the AdoNetAppender, better set the buffer size to some meaningful value for your case to avoid network traffic for every single message. But when the size is reached, the current method that called the log method will be blocked till all messages are sent.

If you don't like that, than you should write your own appender that also derives from `BufferingAppenderSkeleton` and more or less copy the `AdoNetAppender`, but add his own worker thread (or task) that sends the messages asynchronously.

Comment: That's really great. Thanks Oliver.

Comment: I'm going to trial this lad's implementation of some async appenders - https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async It seems to be well regarded

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it logs on the current thread.  Some appenders use buffering to reduce the impact of this, but at some point an application thread's call to a logging method will block while the buffered data is written to its sink.

There have been moves afoot to add asynchronous appenders to log4net, but it's not there yet.